# extensions in VSCode stuck on loading (how to fix)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

In my VScode, whenever I click the "Extensions" button on the left tab, it will stuck on loading forever.
It does not display all the extensions I downloaded previously, as well it is not letting me search for any new extensions, please help!

Comment: Have you already checked if you have any updates for VScode?

Comment: Update your vscode or try with new installation with last stable version

Answer (score 1):

It could be an extension issue. In my case, I had the Apc Electron extension enabled, which caused infinite loading in the Extensions Bar. When I disabled that extension in the Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P > Disable Apc extension) and restarted Visual Studio Code, the infinite loading stopped. If you don't have an extension like Apc Electtron, try disabling others extensions as well. i tried using Ctrl + Shift + P > Reload Window with extensions disabled, but it did not work.